# save copy of existing page as draft in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

I am using wordpress for a website. It's in development i do not have a link to it atm.

My customer would like to have his wife edit/correct the pages he writes, because he's dyslexic.

For new pages, it is simple: just save the page as a draft. Wife can log in and edit, visitors cannot see the page yet.

For existing pages, i don't know how to so that. Is it possible to 
- change an existing page AND
- keep the existing page visible for visitors AND
- hide the updated page from visitors (keep it as draft)?

I prefer having a plugin/mod/extension that does this, but else i'll code it myself.
Thanks for your time.

Kim

Comment: This question is more appropriate for http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: You are right. Sorry for posting here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question has recently been discussed over at wordpress.se.com: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/3986/is-there-any-way-to-draft-a-revision-of-a-published-page-or-post-what-workaround

Unfortunately, there's currently no solution for it but to save the draft as a new page. According to the linked discussion it's possible to make a button that saves as draft, but you'd have to develop the plugin yourself.

Comment: Thank you! This discussion gave me a solution: duplicate post-button. It serves my purposes well enough, even though it's not perfect :-)

Answer (score 4):

Check out the Revisionary WP Plugin:

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/revisionary/

It creates a new user type: revisor who can suggest edits to existing pages that must be approved by an Admin or Editor, and also allows Admins and Editors to create draft copies of existing content to be published later.

Comment: As a developer I like Revisionary... People using it may not, as you can't save work as you go before submission. I had someone in tears as they had worked on a revising page content for four hours, and had accidentally clicked away from the page and lost everything. :(

Answer (score 1):

If you click on "quick edit" in your page list, it will then give you the drop-down menu to change it to a draft. Took me a while to figure that out.

Comment: thank you hhmoscow for your answer. I needed to have a published version of a page and a draft simultaneously. i fixed it by using duplicate post.

Answer (score 1):

You can use duplicate post plugin. With the help of this plugin you can clone wordpress posts or pages easily.

Here is the link : http://wordpress.org/plugins/duplicate-post/

Answer (score 1):

Revisionary is getting a bit old and buggy now, I'm finding "BU Versions" by Boston University a better alternative and looks to do what you wish.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a very clean solution, but cut and paste from the published page into a new draft, call it "Draft of..." and keep it a draft for editing. When the editing is complete, cut and paste into the published page and update, then delete the draft.